# how to configure logging system in one file on python

Tags: python, docker, flask, logging, tcp

I have two files.
first is the TCP server.
second is the flask app. they are one project but they are  inside of a separated docker container
they should write logs same file due to being the same project
ı try to create my logging library  ı import my logging library to two file
ı try lots of things
firstly ı deleted bellow code

```
    if (logger.hasHandlers()):
        logger.handlers.clear()
```

when ı delete,ı get same logs two times

my structure

```
docker-compose
docker file
loggingLib.py
app.py
tcp.py
requirements.txt
.
.
.
```

my last logging code

```
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import time
import os, os.path

project_name= "proje_name"


def get_logger():
    if not os.path.exists("logs/"):
        os.makedirs("logs/")
    now = datetime.now()
    file_name = now.strftime(project_name + '-%H-%M-%d-%m-%Y.log')
    log_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/'+file_name,mode='a', maxBytes=10000000, backupCount=50)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s  ', '%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')

    formatter.converter = time.gmtime
    log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
    if (logger.hasHandlers()):
        logger.handlers.clear()
    logger.addHandler(log_handler)
    return logger
```

it is working but only in one file
if app.py works first, it only makes a log
other file don't make any logs

Comment: Typically in Docker you don't log to a file at all.  Both containers will log to the console, and you can review the logs with `docker logs`.  If you use `docker-compose up` without the `-d` option to launch both containers together on the foreground, their logs will be combined on the console.

Comment: @DavidMaze  ı can't use docker console log because of the volume be overflow. anything that prints docker console fills the overlay memory. in Server memory won't be any empty memory after that, the server can close or can't give any response

Comment: You can configure log rotation for the [default Docker JSON File log driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/).  Logs shouldn't consume memory, only disk space.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried an in made example of docker JSON file log driver 
but ı cant solve may you write a sample to implement in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that directly uses files – config files, log files, data files – is a little trickier to manage in Docker than running locally.  For logs in particular, it's usually better to set your process to log directly to stdout.  Docker will collect the logs, and you can review them with `docker logs`.  In this setup, without changing your code, you can [configure Docker to send the logs somewhere else](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) or use a log collector like fluentd or logstash  to manage the logs.

In your Python code, you usually will want to configure the detailed logging setup at the top level, on the root logger

```py
import logging
def main():
  logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s  ',
    datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',
    level=logging.INFO
  )
  ...
```

and in each individual module you can just get a local logger, which will inherit the root logger's setup

```py
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

With its default setup, Docker will capture log messages into JSON files on disk.  If you generate a large amount of log messages in a long-running container, it can lead to local disk exhaustion (it will have no effect on memory available to processes).  The [Docker logging documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) advises using the [local file logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/local/), which does automatic log rotation.  In a Compose setup you can specify [`logging:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#logging) options:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: local
```

You can also configure log rotation on the [default JSON File logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/):

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: json-file # default, can be omitted
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: 50
```

You "shouldn't" directly access the logs, but they are in a fairly stable format in `/var/lib/docker`, and tools like fluentd and logstash know how to collect them.

If you ever decide to run this application in a cluster environment like Kubernetes, that will have its own log-management system, but again designed around containers that directly log to their stdout.  You would be able to run this application unmodified in Kubernetes, with appropriate cluster-level configuration to forward the logs somewhere.  Retrieving a log file from opaque storage in a remote cluster can be tricky to set up.