# Docker default fs size?

Tags: docker

My app runs into a container and the log files grow up continuously. When will my app stop to work due to lack of disk space ?
This text is just to bypass the boring quality standards

Comment: On modern Docker on native Linux, you can use the entire host disk.  Docker Desktop on non-Linux uses a VM with a configurable disk size.  Also consider writing your logs to stdout rather than files, so that Docker can manage them; I described this setup in [an earlier answer today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768935/how-to-configure-logging-system-in-one-file-on-python/68772796#68772796).

Answer (score 0):

You should map the log folder of your container to a host folder, then you have to schedule a log cleanup policy like `rotatelogs`.